# Figuring out the max value from a series of columns in R

Tags: r

For each observation, there are three volume values, volume_1, volume_2, and volume_3. Sometimes volume_1 is the biggest while sometimes volume_3 is the biggest. Although I feel like this code should be easy, how do I calculate the overall percentage of the time when volume_1 is the biggest, volume_2 is the biggest, and then volume_3 is the biggest.

Here is a little bit of my data

```
structure(list(PVC = c("29A", "2D5", "2HX", "38A", "3CN", "6021051"
), Age = c(6, 5, 6, 10, 5, 7), volume_1 = c(59.44244884, 51.69518257, 
63.17950819, 56.4269955, 64.05189184, 61.82983473), volume_2 = c(54.74897726, 
56.64778447, 51.86880673, 59.71146472, 58.96633234, 63.39471043
), volume_3 = c(58.97596791, 51.75711362, 61.36142512, 57.09629745, 
64.25164825, 63.19407463), Year = c("2003", "2002", "2003", "2008", 
"2003", "1994"), averageAB = c(57.09571305, 54.17148352, 57.52415746, 
58.06923011, 61.50911209, 62.61227258), diff_AB_C = c(-1.88025486, 
2.4143699, -3.83726766, 0.972932659999998, -2.74253616, -0.58180205
), sumAB = c(114.1914261, 108.34296704, 115.04831492, 116.13846022, 
123.01822418, 125.22454516), ratioAB_C = c(1.93623657477333, 
2.09329615703558, 1.87492899154491, 2.03408041163622, 1.91463141461122, 
1.98158681637776)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you as always for your help!!

Comment: `prop.table(table(max.col(df[,grep('^volume_', names(df))])))*100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easily done using the `max.col()` function:

```
df$highest_col <- max.col(df[,3:5])

head(df)
      PVC Age volume_1 volume_2 volume_3 Year averageAB
1     29A   6 59.44245 54.74898 58.97597 2003  57.09571
2     2D5   5 51.69518 56.64778 51.75711 2002  54.17148
3     2HX   6 63.17951 51.86881 61.36143 2003  57.52416
4     38A  10 56.42700 59.71146 57.09630 2008  58.06923
5     3CN   5 64.05189 58.96633 64.25165 2003  61.50911
6 6021051   7 61.82983 63.39471 63.19407 1994  62.61227
   diff_AB_C    sumAB ratioAB_C highest_col
1 -1.8802549 114.1914  1.936237           1
2  2.4143699 108.3430  2.093296           2
3 -3.8372677 115.0483  1.874929           1
4  0.9729327 116.1385  2.034080           2
5 -2.7425362 123.0182  1.914631           3
6 -0.5818020 125.2245  1.981587           2
```

Then you can just run `table()` on that new column to get the counts.

Comment: This was simple and worked great - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way but using tidyverse I'd go

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(max = case_when(max(volume_1, volume_2, volume_3) == volume_1 ~ "volume_1",
                         max(volume_1, volume_2, volume_3) == volume_2 ~ "volume_2",
                         max(volume_1, volume_2, volume_3) == volume_3 ~ "volume_3") %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  count(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` solution.

It finds the name of the column (it's name starting with "volums") thet contains the maximum value of each row. This is stord in te maxCol column.
After that,m using `table` and `prop.table` to get the percentages.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, maxCol := names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)], .SDcols = patterns("^volume")][]
prop.table(table(mydata$maxCol))
# volume_1  volume_2  volume_3 
# 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.1666667
```

of in a oneliner

```
prop.table(table(setDT(mydata)[, .(col = names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)]), .SDcols = patterns("^volume")]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vol <- df %>% select(starts_with("volume"))
vol$max <- colnames(vol)[max.col(vol)]
vol <- 
  vol%>%group_by(max)%>%
  mutate(rep = n(),
  prop = 100* rep/nrow(df)) %>%
  ungroup()

left_join(df,vol)  

Joining, by = c("volume_1", "volume_2", "volume_3")
      PVC Age volume_1 volume_2 volume_3 Year averageAB  diff_AB_C    sumAB ratioAB_C
1     29A   6 59.44245 54.74898 58.97597 2003  57.09571 -1.8802549 114.1914  1.936237
2     2D5   5 51.69518 56.64778 51.75711 2002  54.17148  2.4143699 108.3430  2.093296
3     2HX   6 63.17951 51.86881 61.36143 2003  57.52416 -3.8372677 115.0483  1.874929
4     38A  10 56.42700 59.71146 57.09630 2008  58.06923  0.9729327 116.1385  2.034080
5     3CN   5 64.05189 58.96633 64.25165 2003  61.50911 -2.7425362 123.0182  1.914631
6 6021051   7 61.82983 63.39471 63.19407 1994  62.61227 -0.5818020 125.2245  1.981587
       max rep     prop
1 volume_1   2 33.33333
2 volume_2   3 50.00000
3 volume_1   2 33.33333
4 volume_2   3 50.00000
5 volume_3   1 16.66667
6 volume_2   3 50.00000
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the volume columns, rank the columns in each row and then find the fraction of rank 3 for each.  Multiply that by 100 if percentages are wanted.

How to handle ties was not defined so we used `ties="first"`.  See `?rank` for other possibilities.

```
rowMeans(apply(DF[grep("volume", names(DF))], 1, rank, ties = "first") == 3)
##  volume_1  volume_2  volume_3 
## 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.1666667
```

Here is a variation that gives the same result if there are no ties.

```
vol <- DF[grep("volume", names(DF))]
colMeans(vol == apply(vol, 1, max))
##  volume_1  volume_2  volume_3 
## 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.1666667
```